# Understanding User Relationships and Follow Functionality in Prisma Data Model

Tags: database-design, prisma, data-modeling

I'm working on a social media project and implementing a 'follow' functionality using Prisma. While working on this, I encountered the code given below, where the relations in the User model seem swapped. I'm puzzled as to why 'followers' point to 'following' and vice versa. Could someone explain this? Also, I'm unsure whether this represents a one-to-many relationship or a many-to-many relationship.

```
// Define the User model
model User {
   id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
   username  String   @unique
   // ... other user properties
  
 followers User[] @relation("Following")
 following User[] @relation("Follower")
}

// Define the Follow model to represent the relationship between users
model Follow {
  id          Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  follower    User    @relation("Follower", fields: [followerId], references: [id])
  followerId  Int
  following   User    @relation("Following", fields: [followingId], references: [id])
  followingId Int
  
  @@unique([followerId, followingId])
}
```

Comment: What is your 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question? What do "swapped" & "seem swapped" & "point to" mean, and what is "this"? Is "I'm unsure" trying to ask another question? What question? PS Presumably follow(x,y) iff/when x follows y & via a user we want the sets of users they thus follow & users that thus follow them. How is this different from any case where F(x,y) iff/when x Fs y & given a U we want to get the Us that it Fs & the Us that F it? What do you think this code says about the design, justified by referencing your language & modelling documentation? [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

> I'm puzzled as to why 'followers' point to 'following' and vice versa. Could someone explain this?

Some ambiguity is intrinsic to the reciprocity of those labels:

I take it that, in the **Follow** model, "follower" is who is *following*, while "following" is the user whom the former is a *follower* of.

Then, as for the **User** model consider this: your "follower"s are those who are *following* you, while your "following"s are those you are a *follower* of.

> Also, I'm unsure whether this represents a one-to-many relationship or a many-to-many relationship.

Conceptually, Follow is an n-to-n relationship of User with itself, representing which users are following which users and vice versa: it is anyway implemented as *two* 1-to-n relationships from User to Follow (where Follow is the so called "cross-table").